# how to set startDate in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript

I am using bootstrap datepicker, in this stratDate is set to: -infinity, So I want to change this 01/01/1960

Please help me to change it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean 1/1/1970 as in the beginning of Epoch?

Answer (score 0):

`$('.datepicker').datepicker('update', new Date(1960, 1, 1));`

`$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({defaultDate: "11/1/2013"});`

Really just depends on what date plugin you're using.

Comment: If you could upload the source code, or link to the site I could investigate the problem further and help you find a solution.

Comment: in my datepicker plugin, the default values are-

 var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
  autoclose: false,
  beforeShowDay: $.noop,
  calendarWeeks: false,
  clearBtn: false,
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
  endDate: Infinity,
  forceParse: true,
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  keyboardNavigation: true,
  language: 'en',
  minViewMode: 0,
  orientation: "auto",
  rtl: false,
  startDate: -Infinity,
  startView: 0,
  todayBtn: false,
  todayHighlight: false,
  weekStart: 0
 };

Comment: http://demo.emlearner.com/manager/apply_now.php

this is my live link...

I want to change the start date is 01/01/1960

Comment: Console window reports that `$` is not defined meaing jQuery was not loaded yet. Put the jQuery script tag before your script.

Comment: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>` I recommend the CDN

Answer (score 0):

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scsiva1991/xt1e5gjt/).
 Please check.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', '01-01-1960');
```

Comment: not worked..

http://demo.emlearner.com/manager/apply_now.php

this is link....

see DOB